# "Make into Control" option in Microsoft Blend 2015

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend, uwp

I have tried to use this Tool and I don't understand its purpose. In previous versions, it created a UserControl out of the selected controls. Now it creates a ButtonStyle for what I have seen.

How can I use this tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a little busted in Blend 2022 but here's how you get it working (for posterity).

What happens now is you choose "Make Into UserControl" and then it pops up with a box that asks you to name it.  Then, nothing happens.

Here's the fix:

1. Create a new empty user control and name it however you want it to be named.
2. Go back to the control you want to make into a control, choose "Make Into UserControl" again.  Put the name of the control in there that you just created.

For whatever reason, it silently fails if the user control doesn't exist, but it will write into one that does.

Answer (score -1):

The old Blend has two options, **Make Into UserControl** and **Make Into Control**.

The **Make Into UserControl** wraps whatever you selected into a `UserControl` while the **Make Into Control** has always been turning whatever you selected into a `Custom Control`.

A `Custom Control` generally has a default style, and that's why you see that predefined `ButtonStyle1` on the popup. A `Button` is a `Custom Control`, and that's why you can customize its look and feel by changing its style.

I'd strongly recommend you to have a read on [how to create a `Custom Control`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/15/building-a-custom-control-using-xaml-and-c.aspx).

Comment: OK, I know how to create UserControls. The thing is that I found it very useful the previous "Make Into UserControl" and thought the "Make Into Control" was similar. It doesn't do what I wanted to do, though. Still, I don't know why the "Make Into Control" always renders to a Style for a Button. Why a Button? :(

Comment: Read the answer carefully. "Make into control" doesn't make UserControls... It never does. The other option "Make Into UserControl" is gone in the new blend. You cannot use it anymore.

Comment: OK, so it creates a style for a Button by default. OK, I may find it useful once I understand what it does :)

Comment: Let's say you created an Ellipse and want an Ellipse button.  Where exactly should the Ellipse go? It should go to the ContentTemplate of the button Style. That's why the style was predefined for you on the "make into control" popup.

Comment: @JustinXL, why do you say it's gone in the new Blend? Blend 2015 and Blend 2017 both seem to have it. Did you mean a different version?

Comment: Still are, for me. "Make into control" is only on the Tools menu, however.