# MS Blend for VS 2022 Preview Make Button command missing,

Tags: wpf, blend

I am currently following the Walkthrough for creating a custom button animation using MS blend. The Walkthrough instructs me to use the tool under the Tools Menu 'Make Button' which is not listed. I am using the preview version of VS 2022, I'm not sure if something has changed or if I'm missing a pre-requisite. First time using Blend. Can someone point me in the right direction.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please share a screenshot of what you see in the Tools menu (when you have the Rectangle selected, right?).

Comment: I tried to [follow the walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/walkthrough-create-a-button-by-using-microsoft-expression-blend?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) with Blend 2022 and yeah... the UI is completely changed [and the "Make button" entry is gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040837/make-into-control-option-in-microsoft-blend-2015) - find a more recently updated tutoirial, I guess...

Comment: Thank you Dai. I looked for a newer tutorial thinking that was the issue but it's dated 8/18/2022. I appreciate the confirmation.

Comment: The "8/18/2022" date is the date the article's text was last-modiifed - not when the article was written. The article was actually written waaaaay back around 2010 judging by the Windows 7 screenshots.

Comment: Ah ok. I have reported the documentation, thanks for the help.

Comment: I see you https://github.com/dotnet/docs-desktop/issues/1518